# document.ready() on jQuery plugin init?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a plugin that will create some DIVs and apply styles to them on plugin initialization. In the example code below, I'm doing things like applying `.disableSelection()` to some elements.

Initially I had these things in a `document.ready` wrapper, but then read that that is not the ideal solution, because someone could call the plugin well after the document has been loaded. My understanding is that `document.ready` fires the one time when the document is loaded, and that's it.

If this is the case, what can I use instead of `document.ready` for applying styles and such on plugin initialization?

```
$.examplepluginname = {
 id: 'examplepluginname'
,version: '1.0'
,copyright: 'Copyright (c) 2013 Example Name'
,uri: 'http://www.example.com/'
,licensed: {
    MIT: 'http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php'
    ,GPL: 'http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html'
}
/*,plugin: function(prepare,sort){
    aPluginPrepare.push(prepare);   // function(settings){doStuff();}
    aPluginSort.push(sort);         // function(valuesAreNumeric,sA,sB,iReturn){doStuff();return iReturn;}
}*/
,defaults: { // default settings
    searchDefaultText: 'Search & hit ENTER to add to list' //Text to show when user is not entering a search term
}
};

(function($) {
//Attach this new method to jQuery
$.fn.extend({ 
    //pass the options variable to the function
    examplepluginname: function(options) {

        var userSettings =  $.extend($.examplepluginname.defaults, options)
            //Switcher for when the user presses enter before search results come back
            ,selectOnlyResult = false
            //Arrow key navigation setting
            ,displayBoxIndex = -1
        ;

        /*
            RUN INITIALIZATION SETTINGS
        */
        $("#availableItems").disableSelection();
        displayAvailableItems();
        //Set the display styles    
        $('#tagSearch').css({
            'width': '100%',
            'border-radius': '5px',
            'outline': '0 none',
            'padding': '2px 3px',
            'font-style': 'italic'
        });

        return this.each(function() {
});
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. If this is a plugin you've written, you should apply those styles as part of the plugin initialization on an element...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What do you mean? I intend for someone, for example, to call `$('#examplepluginnamecontainer').examplepluginname();` and have the plugin generate the divs and styles that are required for the plugin to run - just like jQueryUI. Only require the user to make one container, and let the plugin generate the insides.

Comment: Right, so you don't need an event like `$(document).ready()` at all; it has nothing to do with events as far as you're concerned. You do **all of that** inside the function that they call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is the case, what can I use instead of document.ready for applying styles and such on plugin initialization?

If your plugin needs one-time initialization (as opposed to requiring initialization per *use*) and you can't refactor to get rid of that requirement, then your best bet is to have a flag in the plugin indicating whether you've done the init. When the user triggers your plugin (the per-use call), check the flag, do the one-time initialization if necessary and update the flag. Then do the per-use init (regardless of whether you just did the one-time init or not).

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that document.ready fires the one time when the
>   document is loaded, and that's it.

No, that is not a problem. If you call `ready` after the event has happened, it will just call the callback function directly.